# How can I implement swipe up view animation when user tap a button in iPhone application's tool bar?

Tags: iphone, view, transition

First of all, I want to Thank you everyone in this community. All of you are very kind to collaborate this site.

This time, I am going to implement a transition like the instruction below:
1. user tap on a button.
2. another view 'slide' from the bottom.
3. whether user commit filling form or cancel, that view slide down.

The point is, could you help me guide out how to animate that activity? because I seems to implement this with myself, or may be the SDK is ready to work for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at presentModalViewController:animated: in UIViewController. This methode will allow you to display a View Controller on top of another one. You can specify the transition style with the modalTransitionStyle property of the appearing View Controller. UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical is the one you are looking for which is also the default.

Comment: Thank you very much, sliver! This solution work like a charm! I wonder why most content in the book didn't mention this technique. sometime people just need it easy to do.

Comment: I would highly recommend the iTunes U Standford iPhone Course. If you don't have time to watch them all just watch the one about View Controllers it helped me to understand the concept.